# Using row from mysql multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code for getting a row from mysql that shows the time that movie will start.

```
<span class="movie-time"><?php echo $row['movie_start']; ?></span>
<span class="movie-time"><?php echo $row['movie_end']; ?></span>
```

Now during that time i want to put an image that tells the movie is onair so i have this code.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
$currentTime = new DateTime();
$startTime = new DateTime('20:30');
$finishTime = new DateTime('22:30');
```

Now, how can i put a row from mysql in the line startTime and finishTime. It would be perfect if i can put the row that belongs to the time. I tried this code but it doesnt work out.

```
$startTime = new DateTime ($row['movie_start']);
$finishTime = new DateTime ($row['movie_end']);
```

Any help please? Thank you.

Comment: That should work. What error do you get? What are the values of `$row['movie_start']` and `$row['movie_end']`?

Comment: Is that time that i put from mysql like 13:00, 18:30, 20:20,

Comment: Make sure those variables actually contain the value you think they do as that should work.

Comment: I have been trying lots of option, none of them it works, this is the rest of the code, if it would be helpful

    <span id="onair"><img class="on" src="/images/live.gif"></span>
    <span id="onair"><img class="off" src="/images/blank.png"></span>
    
    if ($currentTime >= $finishTime) { $css = 'display:none;'; }
    echo '<style type="text/css">.off {'.$css.'}</style>';
    if ($currentTime < $startTime) { $css = 'display:none;'; }
    else { $css = 'display:block;'; } 
    echo '<style type="text/css">.on {'.$css.'}</style>';

Comment: What does `var_dump($row);` show?

Comment: array(10) { [0]=> string(6) "movie" ["icon"]=> string(6) "movie" [1]=> string(8) "01:50:00" ["movie_start"]=> string(8) "01:50:00" [2]=> string(22) "Inception" ["name"]=> string(22) "Inception" [3]=> string(5) "00:50" ["onair"]=> string(5) "00:50" [4]=> string(107) "Link_1 Link_2" ["links"]=> string(107) "Link_1 Link_2" }

sorry, i dont know how to put the code in the comments

Comment: Those values look ok. You're going to have to tell us what error you get as you haven't made that clear yet.

Comment: The picture is showing up in every row and all time. I wanted to use that picture to show up when visitors come to specified time, for example between 20:30 - 22:30 an image is showing that movie is onair.

Answer (score -1):

**CSS**

```
.onair{background-image:url('images/live.gif');width:100;height:50;}
```

**PHP**

```
if (time() > strtotime($row['movie_start']) &&  strtotime($row['movie_finish'])  > time()){
  echo "<div class=\"onair\"></div>\n";
}
```

If 'movie_start' greater than current time `(time())` 
 AND 'movie_finish' greater than current time
echo a div with a background = live.gif.

time() and strtotime() both use Unix Time.

Convert live.gif to base64 and use in CSS ,like this:

```
 .onair{width:100px;height:50px;    background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,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');}
```

[Site to encode images to base64](http://www.base64-image.de/step-2.php)

Comment: Is works somehow but it show the picture on every row. even on these row that have different time, theoretically that movie hasnt started yet, but it shows the picture. This is the problem. Btw im using this code for strtotime:     
    
    <?php $time = strtotime($row['movie_start']); echo date('H:i', $time); ?>

Comment: `$time = strtotime($row['movie_start']); echo date('H:i', $time);`  is the same as `echo date('H:i', strtotime($row['movie_start']));`

Comment: Thanks so much @Misunderstood, now is working. Had to fix something but is working great. :)

Comment: Thank you.  I like simple and efficient solutions.  Not sure what @JohnConde was thinking with his down vote.  He was a bit too quick to criticize.